# Circles and area of a rectangle

Tags: circles

A circle touches two adjacent sides of a rectangle AB and AD at points P and Q respectively.Third vertex C of the rectangle lies on the circle. The length of perpendicular from vertex C to the chord PQ is 5. Find the area of rectangle.

Comment: I tried but couldn't get anything useful.

Comment: Really.............

Comment: Can points P and Q be located anywhere on the lines AB and AD or are they located at the very end of these lines, the latter resulting in all the vertices of the rectangle laying on the circumference of the circle

Comment: They can be located anywhere.